# slow down/delay frequency display

Tags: javascript, php, fft, web-audio-api, frequency-analysis

```js
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

var audioContext = null;
var isPlaying = false;
var sourceNode = null;
var analyser = null;
var theBuffer = null;
var DEBUGCANVAS = null;
var mediaStreamSource = null;
var detectorElem, 
 pitchElem ;
var testdelay = null;

window.onload = function() {
 audioContext = new AudioContext();
 
 //test delay
 //testdelay = audioContext.createDelay(5.0);
 //testdelay.delayTime.value = 3.0;
 
 MAX_SIZE = Math.max(4,Math.floor(audioContext.sampleRate/5000)); // corresponds to a 5kHz signal
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.open("GET", "../sounds/whistling3.ogg", true);
 request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
 request.onload = function() {
   audioContext.decodeAudioData( request.response, function(buffer) { 
      theBuffer = buffer;
  } );
 }
 request.send();

 detectorElem = document.getElementById( "detector" );
 pitchElem = document.getElementById( "pitch" );


 detectorElem.ondragenter = function () { 
  this.classList.add("droptarget"); 
  return false; };
 detectorElem.ondragleave = function () { this.classList.remove("droptarget"); return false; };
 detectorElem.ondrop = function (e) {
    this.classList.remove("droptarget");
    e.preventDefault();
  theBuffer = null;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
     audioContext.decodeAudioData( event.target.result, function(buffer) {
       theBuffer = buffer;
     }, function(){alert("error loading!");} ); 

    };
    reader.onerror = function (event) {
     alert("Error: " + reader.error );
  };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
    return false;
 };
}

function error() {
    alert('Stream generation failed.');
}

function getUserMedia(dictionary, callback) {
    try {
        navigator.getUserMedia = 
         navigator.getUserMedia ||
         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
         navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
        navigator.getUserMedia(dictionary, callback, error);
    } catch (e) {
        alert('getUserMedia threw exception :' + e);
    }
}

function gotStream(stream) {
    // Create an AudioNode from the stream.
    mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
 
    // Connect it to the destination.
    analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();

 //test delay
 //testdelay = audioContext.createDelay(5.0);
 //testdelay.delayTime.value = 3.0;
 
 
 //analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.8;
 
    analyser.fftSize = 8192;
    mediaStreamSource.connect( analyser );
 
    updatePitch();
}

function toggleLiveInput() {
    if (isPlaying) {
        //stop playing and return
        sourceNode.stop( 0 );
        sourceNode = null;
        analyser = null;
        isPlaying = false;
  if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
   window.cancelAnimationFrame = window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame;
        window.cancelAnimationFrame( rafID );
    }
    getUserMedia(
     {
            "audio": {
                "mandatory": {
                    "googEchoCancellation": "false",
                    "googAutoGainControl": "false",
                    "googNoiseSuppression": "false",
                    "googHighpassFilter": "false"
                },
                "optional": []
            },
        }, gotStream);
}


var buf = new Float32Array( 1024 );


var MIN_SAMPLES = 0;  // will be initialized when AudioContext is created.

function autoCorrelate( buf, sampleRate ) {
 var SIZE = buf.length;
 var MAX_SAMPLES = Math.floor(SIZE/2);
 var best_offset = -1;
 var best_correlation = 0;
 var rms = 0;
 var foundGoodCorrelation = false;
 var correlations = new Array(MAX_SAMPLES);

 for (var i=0;i<SIZE;i++) {
  var val = buf[i];
  rms += val*val;
 }
 
 rms = Math.sqrt(rms/SIZE);
 if (rms<0.01) // not enough signal
  return -1;

 
 var lastCorrelation=1;
 for (var offset = MIN_SAMPLES; offset < MAX_SAMPLES; offset++) {
  var correlation = 0;

  for (var i=0; i<MAX_SAMPLES; i++) {
   correlation += Math.abs((buf[i])-(buf[i+offset]));
  }
  
  correlation = 1 - (correlation/MAX_SAMPLES);
  
  // store it, for the tweaking we need to do below.
  correlations[offset] = correlation; 
  
  if ((correlation>0.9) && (correlation > lastCorrelation)) {
   foundGoodCorrelation = true;
   if (correlation > best_correlation) {
    best_correlation = correlation;
    best_offset = offset;
   }
  } else if (foundGoodCorrelation) {
   var shift = (correlations[best_offset+1] - correlations[best_offset-1])/correlations[best_offset];  
   return sampleRate/(best_offset+(8*shift));
  }
  
  lastCorrelation = correlation;
 }
 if (best_correlation > 0.01) {
  // console.log("f = " + sampleRate/best_offset + "Hz (rms: " + rms + " confidence: " + best_correlation + ")")
  return sampleRate/best_offset;
 }
 return -1;
// var best_frequency = sampleRate/best_offset;
}


//Fungsi untuk melakukan Update/perubahan data frequensi
function updatePitch( time ) {
 var cycles = new Array;
 analyser.getFloatTimeDomainData( buf );
 analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.8;
 var ac = autoCorrelate( buf, audioContext.sampleRate );
 
 //menampilkan data pada form
 //jika tidak ditemukanya gelombang maka data akan kosong, dan warna tampilan akan abu2
  if (ac == -1) {
   detectorElem.className = "vague";
   pitchElem.innerText = "";

 //jika ditemukanya gelombang maka data akan kosong, dan warna tampilan akan hitam dan data akan ditampilkan
  } else {
   detectorElem.className = "confident";
   pitch = ac;
  
  //menampilkan data "pitch" (--Hz) pada halaman Web
   pitchElem.innerText = Math.round( pitch ) ;
 }

 if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
  window.requestAnimationFrame = window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame;
 rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame( updatePitch );
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pitch Detector</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alike' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
body { font: 14pt 'Alike', sans-serif;}
#note { font-size: 164px; }
.droptarget { background-color: #348781}
div.confident { color: black; }
div.vague { color: lightgrey; }
#note { display: inline-block; height:180px; text-align: left;}

#detector { width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 4px solid gray; border-radius: 8px; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;}
#output { width: 300px; height: 42px; }
#flat { display: none; }
#sharp { display: none; }
.flat #flat { display: inline; }
.sharp #sharp { display: inline; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<script src="js/pitchdetect.js"></script>
 
<!--  <button onclick="this.innerText = togglePlayback()">use demo audio</button> -->
<center>
<button onclick="toggleLiveInput()">use live input</button>

<!--<button onclick="updatePitch(0);">sample</button>-->

<div id="detector" class="vague">
 <div class="pitch"><span id="pitch">--</span>Hz</div>
 <div class="note"><span id="note">--</span></div>   
 <canvas id="output" width=300 height=42></canvas>
 <div id="detune"><span id="detune_amt">--</span><span id="flat">cents &#9837;</span><span id="sharp">cents &#9839;</span></div>
</div>


<!-- just used for debugging
<canvas id="waveform" width="512" height="256"></canvas>
-->

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35593052-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

did anyone have experience making a live frequency meter on web (php,javascript) using microphone?

i have a project to make a online live frequency meter. to display frequency number so we can record if the product were good or not. 
but the frequency number run too fast..

can  any one help me, how to skip some updatePicht() or some way to delay the display, for making it easier to look?
or the way to smooth the value...

Answer (score 0):

I think you basically have to smooth the frequency estimate you get from updatePitch() yourself.  Either call updatePitch less frequently, which is probably not what you want or do some kind of running average of the values returned by updatePitch.

Comment: i have try it, but it not work...
can you fix my Code Please, Or can you give a an Example to do it?

Comment: Well, one simple approach.  Let `f` be the output from `updatePitch()`. Instead of displaying `updatePitch()`, compute `f = a*updatePitch() + (1-a)*f` where `a` is some small number, perhaps, 0.25?  You'll have to experiment a bit, but the smaller `a` is, the less variation there will be in the pitch, but you won't catch sudden pitch changes either.